# Compress Empty Folder with Chinese characters,but result not Folder

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ZipOutputStream o1 = getZipOut(new File("C:\\Users\\chanc\\Desktop\\output1.zip"));
    ZipOutputStream o2 = getZipOut(new  File("C:\\Users\\chanc\\Desktop\\output2.zip"));
    ZipOutputStream o3 = getZipOut(new File("C:\\Users\\chanc\\Desktop\\output3.zip"));
    ZipOutputStream o4 = getZipOut(new  File("C:\\Users\\chanc\\Desktop\\output4.zip"));
    ZipOutputStream o5 = getZipOut(new File("C:\\Users\\chanc\\Desktop\\output5.zip"));

    createEmptyFolder(o1,"a b c d ee ff gg hhh/");
    createEmptyFolder(o2,"一 二 三 四/");
    createEmptyFolder(o3,"一 二 三 四 english/");
    createEmptyFolder(o4,"一二三四/");
    createEmptyFolder(o5,"嗯嗯嗯嗯/");

}

public static ZipOutputStream getZipOut(File file ) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
}

public static void createEmptyFolder(ZipOutputStream os,String location) throws IOException {
    os.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(location));
    os.closeEntry();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

I create five zip files,and add one empty entry in each zip file in order to create a empty folder. The result below you can see

[one --(a b c d ee ff gg hhh) is folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWCn8.jpg)

[two --(一 二 三 四) is NOT folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TsIM.jpg)

[three --(一 二 三 四 english) is folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY1r1.jpg)

[four --(一二三四) is NOT folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnPbM.jpg)

[five --(嗯嗯嗯嗯) -- is folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXWYh.jpg)

As you can see , 
NO.4 is not a folder in zip but NO.5 is a folder in zip. But they have no difference except the name of the folder.

There is no problem if the folder name is not Chinese or contains not Chinese character.

What is the correct way to create a empty folder in zip using ZipOutputStream?

Comment: Can you change your folder name and check if that is creating an empty folder or not.

Comment: as you see, some folder name like (嗯嗯嗯嗯) if will create an empty folder. But the folder name like (一二三四), it will create a File

Comment: That is what I am saying, for folder name which is not creating an empty folder, try some different name and check. If it creates the folder or not.

Comment: I have try a lot of name like (阿斯蒂芬) or (大啊啊大神幅) - is folder  but (安防主线程) or (认为这发送到额) -is not folder. I didn't find any  regular pattern in it